# Sifr Font last word get cut in IE8

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-8, sifr

Sifr 3 font cut last word in IE8.
[Click here for snapshot](http://www.shah-ent.com/temp/font-issue.jpg)

Following is the js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var cochin = {
  src: '<?=jsPath?>sifr/fonts/eurostile.swf'
  ,ratios: [7, 1.32, 11, 1.31, 13, 1.24, 14, 1.25, 19, 1.23, 27, 1.2, 34, 1.19, 42, 1.18, 47, 1.17, 48, 1.18, 69, 1.17, 74, 1.16, 75, 1.17, 1.16]
};

sIFR.activate(cochin);


sIFR.replace(cochin, {
  selector: 'h1'
  ,css: [
    '.sIFR-root { font-weight: bold; font-size:31px; color:#848484; text-transform:uppercase; display:inline;}'
  ]
  ,wmode: 'transparent'

});

sIFR.fitExactly = true;
sIFR.forceWidth = true;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tuneWidth` parameter to make the Flash movie a bit wider, so that the text will fit.